# Android resource compilation failed - resource file not found

Tags: gradle, bamboo

I'm trying to assemble an Android app in Bamboo server, but I'm getting this error when the *assemble* comand run. Note: It works perfectly in local.

Command running:

> gradlew assembleDebug

And the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\aa6199e981580f79dc21c6ea06a3575f\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\quantum_ic_skip_next_white_24.png: error: file not found.
```

I've checked for the resource and its use, but it's not from my project code. It belongs to an external library: *play-services-cast-framework*

I've been also checking other similar post, but the error can be caused for many resources reasons, so I've not found a solution.

Some solutions suggest that is a problem at some gradle plugin version, but I'm already using version 3.3.1

Any help or clue?
Thanks!